# How can I ping a Networked AV Receiver with UDP?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I've been working with a [Denon AVR-X1100W](http://usa.denon.com/us/product/hometheater/avreceiversht/avrx1100w) in an effort to find out whether or not I can ping it over a local network. For this, I am using C# in order to make a simple program.

*How can I ping this type of device?* A traditional ping command doesn't work, however, as it lacks an actual web server internally. I understand that a socket needs to be opened and, from there, a specific message sent with UDP.

Beyond creating a socket, I am unsure on how to continue.

Comment: After creating a socket, send a sequence of bytes. Preferably something that this device will understand and respond to...

Comment: Let's assume that I know what bytes to send. What is the syntax used for sending bytes? That is the question I am asking.

Comment: Search the Internet for 'c# UDP example' and you'll get tons of information. I also suggest the use of Sysinternals TCPView and HWGroup Hercules for testing and debugging,  See my answers on other networking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a great JavaScript-based library, [denon-avr](https://github.com/phillipsnick/denon-avr), that helped me connect to the receiver.

While this resulted in a change from C# to JavaScript, I found using JS to be much more agreeable in terms of development.